# Why does window.alert work differently in inline script and external script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, alert

In the case of an inline script I see white blank page and alert window, after closing it content of the page is displayed, in case of external script I see content of the page and alert window simultaneously. Why does it happen?

HTML code, inline script:

```
<body>
  <!--content-->
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <script>
    alert();
  </script>
</body>
```

HTML code, external script.

```
<body>
  <!--content-->
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <script src="script.js">
  </script>
</body>
```

script.js.

```
alert();
```

Comment: FWIW, it's not that `alert` specifically works differently but rather when/how the browser executes the JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, definitely not the best choice of words from my side.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible, since the browser assigns priority for resources loaded from external links.

Check:

https://addyosmani.com/blog/script-priorities/
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/priority-hints